# ASP.NET Horizontal drag and scroll for GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, drag

So, I have this really large GridView inside an Update Panel, and I want to make it horizontally drag-scrollable.
I've tried almost everything, the problem is basically the drag function, beacuse the overflow does work.

Any suggestion? Is there a way to make it function with simple javascript instead of jQuery or it's just a dream?

(http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html this is a perfect example of what I'm searching for, but I can't find the source code.)

Comment: Just place it in a DIV with fixed dimensions and `overflow:scroll`. The only drawback - vertical scroll will hide the headers

Comment: Yeah, this is what I've done. But what about the mouse drag?